# ng-show with conditional values gives 2 different issues on same partial

Tags: angularjs

I have the following partial where some expression has

example : ng-show="'{{selectedtournoi.tournois_simple}}'==1"

On the first occurence it provides true evaluation, not on the second one.

I checked my html tags, they sound well formed.

I don't understand this behavior;

full code:

```
<div  Class='' ng-controller="tournoisCtrl">
    <div class="">
        &nbsp;
    </div>

<!-- Liste des tournois -->
    <div ng-show="showtournoislist">
        <div ng-show="tournois.tournois.length" class="">
            <ul id="tournois-list">
                <li ng-repeat="tournoi in tournois.tournois track by $index">
                    <div class="tournois">
                        <div class='row'>
                            <span class='tournois_title'>{{tournoi.tournois_title}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <span class='tournois_dates'>Du {{tournoi.tournois_date_debut | date:'d-M-yyyy'}} au {{tournoi.tournois_date_fin | date:'d-M-yyyy'}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <span class='tournois_dates'> Limite d'inscription : {{tournoi.tournois_date_limite | date:'d-M-yyyy'}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <a ng-click="toggleshowtournois(tournoi.tournois_id)"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">En savoir plus</button></a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Détail d'un tournoi -->

    <div ng-show="!showtournoislist">
           <ul class="tournois">
                <div>
                    <span class='tournois_title'>{{selectedtournoi.tournois_title}}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class='tournois_dates'>Du {{selectedtournoi.tournois_date_debut | date:'d-M-yyyy'}} au {{selectedtournoi.tournois_date_fin | date:'d-M-yyyy'}}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class='tournois_dates'> Limite d'inscription : {{selectedtournoi.tournois_date_limite | date:'d-M-yyyy'}}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class='tournois_dates'> Tournoi financé : {{selectedtournoi.tournois_decompte}}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class='tournois_dates'> Description : {{selectedtournoi.tournois_description}}</span>
                </div>                                
                <div>
                    <a ng-click="showinscris=!showinscris"><button class='badge'>{{selectedinscris.length}} inscris</button></a>
                </div>
<!-- Liste des inscrits-->
                <div ng-show="showinscris">

                        <div ng-repeat="tinsc in selectedinscris" class="tournois_dates">
                            <span class="tournois_inscris_name">{{tinsc.fullname}}</span><br>
                            <span ng-show="'{{selectedtournoi.tournois_simple}}'==1">Simple ({{tinsc.inscriptions_simple_serie}})</span>
                            <br ng-show="'{{tinsc.inscriptions_double_partenaire}}'!=''"><span ng-show="'{{tinsc.inscriptions_double_partenaire}}'">Double ({{tinsc.inscriptions_double_serie}})</span>
                            <span ng-show="'{{tinsc.inscriptions_double_partenaire}}'!=''"> avec {{tinsc.inscriptions_double_partenaire}} / {{tinsc.inscriptions_double_partenaire_club}}</span>
                            <br ng-show="'{{tinsc.inscriptions_mixte_partenaire}}'!=''"><span ng-show="'{{tinsc.inscriptions_mixte_partenaire}}'">Mixte ({{tinsc.inscriptions_mixte_serie}})</span>
                            <span ng-show="'{{tinsc.inscriptions_mixte_partenaire}}'!=''">avec {{tinsc.inscriptions_mixte_partenaire}} / {{tinsc.inscriptions_mixte_partenaire_club}}</span>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div ng-show="!logguedinscris">
                            <span ng-show="Loggued">
                                <span ng-show="!showLimite">
                                    <a href  ng-show="!showinscription" ng-click="showinscription=!showinscription"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Participer</button></a>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="!Loggued">
                             <span ng-show="!showLimite">Vous devez vous <a ui-sref="login">identifier</a> pour participer</span>
                </div>

                <br>                
<!--Mon inscription-->
                <div>
                    <form ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-show='!showLimite'>
                            <!-- Simple-->
                            <!-- participation -->
                            <div class="form-group"  ng-show="'{{selectedtournoi.tournois_simple}}'==1">
                                <label>Simple</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cbSimple" ng-click="showSi=!showSi" ng-checked="forminscris.inscriptions_simple==1" ng-model="forminscris.inscriptions_simple" >
                            <!-- Serie -->
                                <label ng-show="showSi">Serie</label>
                                <select ng-show="showSi" ng-options="item as item for item in selectedtournoi.tournois_xserie_simple track by item" ng-model="selectedSerieSimple"></select>                            </div>                
                            <div class="form-group" ng-show="'{{selectedtournoi.tournois_double}}'==1">
                                <label>Double</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cbDouble"  ng-click="showDbl=!showDbl" ng-checked="forminscris.inscriptions_double==1" ng-model="forminscris.inscriptions_double">

                                <label ng-show="showDbl">Serie</label>                             
                                <select ng-show="showDbl" ng-options="item as item for item in selectedtournoi.tournois_xserie_double track by item" ng-model="selectedSerieDouble"></select>
                                <br ng-show="showDbl">
                                <label ng-show="showDbl">Partenaire</label><br ng-show="showDbl">
                                <label ng-show="showDbl">Bacly ? </label><input type="checkbox" ng-show="showDbl" name="BaclyDbl" ng-checked="showBaclyDbl==true" ng-click="showBaclyDbl=!showBaclyDbl"><br ng-show="showDbl">

                                <select ng-show="showBaclyDbl && showDbl" ng-model="selectedPartenaireDoubleBacly" ng-options="item.user_id as item.fullname for item in baclyusersdouble.users" class="selectuser"></select>

                                <input type="text" name="partenaireDouble"  ng-show="!showBaclyDbl && showDbl" ng-model="forminscris.inscriptions_double_partenaire">
                                <br ng-show="showDbl">
                                <label  ng-show="!showBaclyDbl && showDbl">Club :</label><br ng-show="showDbl">
                                <input type="text"  ng-show="!showBaclyDbl && showDbl" name="clubPartenaireDouble"  ng-model="forminscris.inscriptions_double_partenaire_club">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group"  ng-show="'{{selectedtournoi.tournois_mixte}}'==1">
                                <label>Mixte</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cbMixte" ng-click="showMx=!showMx" ng-checked="forminscris.inscriptions_mixte==1" ng-model="forminscris.inscriptions_mixte">
                    <!--            <p ng-show="form.userForm.name.$invalid && !form.userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>-->
                            <!-- Serie -->
                                <label ng-show="showMx">Serie</label>
                                <select ng-show="showMx" ng-options="item as item for item in selectedtournoi.tournois_xserie_mixte track by item" ng-model="selectedSerieMixte"></select>
                                <br ng-show="showMx">
                                <label ng-show="showMx">Partenaire</label><br ng-show="showMx">
                                <label ng-show="showMx">Bacly ? </label><input type="checkbox" name="BaclyMx" ng-checked="showBaclyMx==true"  ng-click="showBaclyMx=!showBaclyMx" ng-show="showMx"><br ng-show="showMx">

                                <select ng-show="showBaclyMx && showMx" ng-model="selectedPartenaireMixteBacly" ng-options="item.user_id as item.fullname for item in baclyusersmixte.users" class="selectuser"></select>

                                <input type="text"  ng-show="!showBaclyMx && showMx"  name="partenaireMixte"  ng-model="forminscris.inscriptions_mixte_partenaire">
                                <br ng-show="showMx">
                                <label ng-show="!showBaclyMx && showMx" >Club :</label><br ng-show="showMx">
                                <input type="text" ng-show="!showBaclyMx && showMx" name="clubPartenaireMixte"  ng-model="forminscris.inscriptions_mixte_partenaire_club">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Commentaire</label>
                                <input type="text" name="commentaire" placeholder="" ng-model="forminscris.inscriptions_comment">
                            </div>                            
                            <br>
                            <div class=''>
                                     <a href  ng-click="insertinscription()"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-show="Loggued && !logguedinscris">M'inscrire</button></a>
                                     <a href  ng-click="showinscription=!showinscription"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-show="!logguedinscris">Annuler</button></a>
                                     <a href  ng-click="updateinscription()"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-show="Loggued && logguedinscris" >Mettre à jour</button></a>
                                     <a href  ng-click="deleteinscription()"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-show="Loggued && logguedinscris" >Me désinscrire</button></a>
                            </div>
                     </form>
                </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Dont use interpolation `{{` in ng-show expression, i.e just do `ng-show="'selectedtournoi.tournois_simple==1"` for example

Comment: examples should be in English, not in French

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the interpolation is necessary inside the `ng-show` directive attribute.

You can use `ng-show = " selectedtournoi.tournois_simple == 1 "`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thx buddies, it works great indeed